# Android SE App crashes if you try use "Web Search"

Tags: bug, android-app

App version: 1.0.26

Device happen on: Nexus 7 2013, Huawei Ascend G510

If you highlight some text in a question and then click on the **Web Search** option, the app crashes (logcat provided below).

```
03-22 00:01:44.919 E/AndroidRuntime(14618): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-22 00:01:44.919 E/AndroidRuntime(14618): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.WEB_SEARCH (has extras) }
03-22 00:01:44.919 E/AndroidRuntime(14618):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1632)
03-22 00:01:44.919 E/AndroidRuntime(14618):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
03-22 00:01:44.919 E/AndroidRuntime(14618):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3390)
03-22 00:01:44.919 E/AndroidRuntime(14618):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3351)
03-22 00:01:44.919 E/AndroidRuntime(14618):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3587)
03-22 00:01:44.919 E/AndroidRuntime(14618):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3555)
03-22 00:01:44.919 E/AndroidRuntime(14618):     at android.webkit.SelectActionModeCallback.onActionItemClicked(SelectActionModeCallback.java:129)
03-22 00:01:44.919 E/AndroidRuntime(14618):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView$ActionModeCallbackWrapper.onActionItemClicked(PhoneWindow.java:2569)
03-22 00:01:44.919 E/AndroidRuntime(14618):     at com.android.internal.view.StandaloneActionMode.onMenuItemSelected(StandaloneActionMode.java:133)
03-22 00:01:44.919 E/AndroidRuntime(14618):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735)
03-22 00:01:44.919 E/AndroidRuntime(14618):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
03-22 00:01:44.919 E/AndroidRuntime(14618):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
03-22 00:01:44.919 E/AndroidRuntime(14618):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.onItemClick(MenuPopupHelper.java:156)
03-22 00:01:44.919 E/AndroidRuntime(14618):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
03-22 00:01:44.919 E/AndroidRuntime(14618):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1100)
03-22 00:01:44.919 E/AndroidRuntime(14618):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2788)
03-22 00:01:44.919 E/AndroidRuntime(14618):     at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3463)
03-22 00:01:44.919 E/AndroidRuntime(14618):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
03-22 00:01:44.919 E/AndroidRuntime(14618):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-22 00:01:44.919 E/AndroidRuntime(14618):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-22 00:01:44.919 E/AndroidRuntime(14618):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
03-22 00:01:44.919 E/AndroidRuntime(14618):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-22 00:01:44.919 E/AndroidRuntime(14618):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-22 00:01:44.919 E/AndroidRuntime(14618):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
03-22 00:01:44.919 E/AndroidRuntime(14618):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-22 00:01:44.919 E/AndroidRuntime(14618):     at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:126)
03-22 00:01:44.919 E/AndroidRuntime(14618):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native     Method)
03-22 00:01:44.919 W/ActivityManager(  516):   Force finishing activity com.stackexchange.marvin/.ui.ViewPopupActivity
```

Also if you highlight some code in a question and then click on the menu and the text colour of **Find** and **Web Search** options are black, instead of white like the rest of the text.

[image: black text on dark background menu]

Comment: I added the two devices that I could reproduce this on. It doesn't  happen on a Toshiba AT10.

Comment: I've never seen this "Web Search" option before in my life. Is this something custom on your phone? Do you see this in every app that lets you select text?

Comment: I never saw it either until I noticed it there. It shows on the Gmail and Chrome app but not the ColorNote, ES File Explorer app or one I made myself.

Comment: Not repro'd on Nexus 5, Android 6.0.1, SE app v1.0.83, but it might be related to Android issue, not SE app. AFAIK, Android/Google/Chrome adds "Web Search" when highlighting a text as a shortcut to search on Google app, and it's out of Stack Exchange's control to fix it. As for the second issue, it's should be on-topic since it could be fixed on SE app (issue related to app's theme).